# htaccess to redirect to a random link

Tags: .htaccess

How can i redirect a image link to other several random sources?

If for example http://www.example.com/logo.jpg to come from http://tinypic.com/something.jpg **OR** http://i.imgur.com/something.jpg

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/logo.jpg$ http://tinypic.com/something.jpg ?? http://i.imgur.com/something.jpg [P,L]
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to randomly select an URL to redirect to in `.htaccess`.

You'll have to do the random selection using an other language like php.
Redirect the request to an php file on the server, which either loads the random file from remote or sends a redirect header to the Browser.